# Resetting $V{REPORT_COUNT} for each group in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` in JasperReports to print serial number and it works well. But when I grouped by a field and started each group on a new page the serial number still continues across the groups.

I need to reset this variable `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` for each group.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a count that resets on each page, then that's not `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` by definition.

It sounds like you want the built-in variable `$V{PAGE_COUNT}`. Or you might want the built-in `$V{MyGroup_COUNT}`.

More generally you could create your own variable to count what you want. But the built-in ones probably meet your needs in this case.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. I just noticed another error and I think maybe you might be able to help. PAGE_NUMBER which was used in 'Page x of y' is correct for x but wrong for y because it gives me the total pages printed for the last group not for the current group. I tried to see if there was a variable like MyGroup_NUMBER, but there happens to be none. Please, how can I define a variable to give me the total pages for the current group?

Comment: My immediate guess is that there is no built-in variable. But you should be able to create one. Give it a try with a variable that resets each group and increments on page change. If you get stuck, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new group in i report, a new variable will be automatically created in variables of ireport. Take that instead of report count. the sl no will start with 1 for each group.

Comment: And what is the name of the newly created variable? Or how can I figure out the name?

Answer (score 0):

the variable is created by the group name eg. if groupname is grp1 then variable created is grp1_count